# What is the $q$ for the formula $S_n=\frac{a_1(1-q^n)}{(1-q)}$ with given $a_1$,$ S_n$ and $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

As the title says everything.

Thanks,

Comment: Look here its called $r$,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: If you are looking to find $q(a_1, S_n, n)$, there is no generic formula for $n > 4$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $s=\dfrac{S_n}{a_1}$ for conciseness.

You need to solve the polynomial equation

$$s(1-q)=1-q^n,$$
or
$$P_n(q)=q^n-sq+s-1=0.$$

There is no analytical solution for general $n$ and you need to resort to numerical methods. [Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) works well for this case. Iterate with

$$q\leftarrow q-\frac{P_n(q)}{P'_n(q)}=\frac{nq^n-s+1}{nq^{n-1}-s}.$$

An intial bracketing can be found from

$$s_1=1+q<s<\frac1{1-q}=s_\infty,$$ so that

$$1-\frac1s<q<s-1.$$

And a better approximation can be obtained as the first step of the secant method, with

$$q\leftarrow \frac{P_n(q_1)q_0-P_n(q_0)q_1}{P_n(q_1)-P_n(q_0)},$$where $q_1=1-\dfrac1s$ and $q_0=s-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $q=1+r$ with some small value $r$ for the interest rate (assuming no usury) one gets $q-1=r$ and $q^n-1=nr+\frac{n(n-1)}2r^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}r^3+…$ so that approximately
$$
r_0=\frac{S}{na}-1\approx \frac{n-1}2r·\left(1+\frac{n-2}3r\right)
$$
Multiplying with $\left(1-\frac{n-2}3r\right)$ and ignoring higher-order terms results in
$$
r_0=\left(\frac{n-1}2+\frac{n-2}3r_0\right)r
\\ \iff \\
r = \frac{6r_0}{3(n-1)+2(n-2)r_0}
$$
as a good initial first approximation for starting Newtons method or the secant method or ...