# How to calculate the interest rate in the below problem?

Tags: finance

A loan of £12,000 is issued and is repaid in instalments of £300 at the end of each month for 4  years. Calculate the effective annual rate of interest for this loan.

**What I tried.**
The equation of value is
$$
12,000=3,600\,a_{\overline{4}|}^{(12)}
$$

But how to solve this equation for $i$?

Please help.

Comment: Compound or simple interest?

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701704/get-rate-in-excel-without-using-rate-command/1701727#1701727

Comment: @N.S.JOHN compound...

Comment: I can't read your equation, could you edit it using TeX?

Answer (score 0):

The equation is

$$\large{12,000\cdot (1+\frac{i}{12})^{48}=300\cdot \frac{\left(1+ \frac{i}{12} \right)^{48}-1}{\frac{i}{12}}}$$.

Substituting $1+\frac{i}{12}$  by $x$.

$12,000\cdot x^{48}=300\cdot \frac{x^{48}-1}{x-1} \qquad |\cdot (x-1)$

$12,000\cdot x^{49}-12,000\cdot x^{48}=300\cdot x^{48}-300$

$12,000\cdot x^{49}-12,300\cdot x^{48}+300=0$

This is a 49th degree polynomial. It cannot be solved algebraically. Therefore you have to use an approximation method, for instance the [Newton–Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Answer (score 0):

For a loan of $12,000$ and payments $P=300$ at monthly interest rate $i_m$ for $n=48$ months, you have to solve 
$$
L=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i_m}\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \frac{1-(1+i_m)^{-48}}{i_m}=40
$$
and you can solve it numerically and find $i_m\approx 0.77\%$. Thus the effective annual rate of interest $i$ is
$$
i=(1+i_m)^{12}-1\approx 9.64\%
$$

Comment: $(1+0.0077)^{1/12}-1\approx 0.000639$. This doesn´t fit with your result of $9.64\%$

Comment: It's to power 12, not 1/12.