# Calculate APR from loan, monthly payments, and amount of months

Tags: finance

For some reason calculating APR is very difficult. A lot of people ask, but not a lot of great answers. I'm working on a project, where I need to calculate APR. I have already calculated what the loan is, how much the user has to pay each month, and I have the amount of months. I found a formula online, but it doesn't make a lot of sense.

```
function calculateAPR(loan, repayments, months) {
    var p = 1;
    var tmp = 1;
    var a = p;
    var b = 0;
    while (Math.abs(tmp) > 0.0001) {
        p = (a - b) / 2 + b;
        tmp = (loan / repayments) - (1 - Math.pow(1 + p, -months)) / p;
        if (tmp > 0) {
            a = p;
        } else {
            b = p;
        }
    }
    var apr = Math.pow((1 + p), 12) - 1;
    return apr;
}
```

`Math.pow()`'s second argument is what you want to power by an amount. Basically `1+p^12` on the third last line. `Math.abs()` returns the absolute value (`-10` becomes `10`). If I input this:

```
loan = 80000
repayments = 7366
months = 12
```

I get an APR of `20.56%`. That seems correct according to the site I got the formula from, but when I input the numbers into other websites, I get no where near the same result.

Can someone explain how this formula works? Why is there a loop? Is it because of compound interest? Is there a better formula? I'm looking for any kind of help, because I can't seem to find answers that solve this programmably. Thanks.

Comment: You could be interested by http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536653/approximating-the-compond-interest-for-a-loan

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I appreciate your comment! However, it looks like that person gave up (last line of his answer) :(

Comment: What makes you think that code is wrong? For the example you gave, which sites give answers other than the one you got from the code?

Comment: @MortenMoulder. This was a post of mine ! You can use the results for an estimate and start using Newton or whichever method you want.

Comment: @quasi I don't think the code is wrong. I just don't understand how it works and why there is a loop. Why I think it might be wrong, is because all the other calculators I tried, this one shows a different result each time.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can you explain what the numbers are? `r = 0.01` and `n = 180`?

Comment: @MortenMoulder: Can you give a link to an online APR calculator that gives an answer other than the one produced by the code for the example you posted?

Comment: @quasi You can try this one: http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/apr-calculator.php - I already know the loan, repayments (monthly), and the total amount of months.

Comment: @MortenMoulder: that website gives the _same_ answer as your program, using the following inputs:
\begin{align*}
\text{loan}&=80,000.00\\
\text{interest rate}&= 20.5406\\
\text{compounding}&= \text{annual}\\
\text{number of payments}&= 12\\
\text{payment frequency}&= \text{monthly}\\
\text{all fees}&= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: @MortenMoulder: You can lso use EXCEL: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IRR-function-64925eaa-9988-495b-b290-3ad0c163c1bc

Comment: @quasi The interest rate is not $20.5406$ though? Where did you get that from?

Comment: @cgiovanardi No Excel.

Comment: @MortenMoulder: Why is that not the interest rate? An interest rate of 20.5406% is consistent with the input data.

Comment: @quasi Where did you get it from? I only know $loan = 80,000.00$, $number  of  payments = 12$ and $monthly  repayments = 8,000.00$ - Based on those 3 numbers, how do you get $interest rate = 20.5406$?

Comment: @MortenMoulder: That rate comes from your posted formula, and it also matches the results from the online calculator for which you posted a link.

Comment: @quasi We agree that the formula I posted and the formula on that website are basically the same? Let's imagine I didn't have my formula, but I only had the website. How would you get the interest rate then?

Comment: @MortenMoulder: Look way back in the comments. I gave you the inputs for the website.

Comment: @quasi I don't think you understand. Based on these three numbers: $loan = 80000$, $number of months = 12$, and $repayments = 7366$ how do you get the interest rate just from that website I sent you? Forget the interest rate, because that is completely unknown.

Comment: That website doesn't calculate the interest rate. You have to enter the interest rate as _input_. It then calculates the monthly payment. But the site can be used to _verify_ that the results based on your code are correct. Look back in the comments -- I _specified_ the inputs I used to check the results from the code. The results _checked_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is designed to progressively narrow the interval in which the correct apr resides. At the outset, the program assumes (arbitrarily) that the correct monthly apr, $r$ say, is between $0$ and $1$ (i.e., between $0\text{%}$ and  $100\text{%}$).

The variables $a,b$ denotes the bounds on $r$, where $b \le r \le a$.

As the program progresses, the values of $a$ and $b$ are adjusted, as follows . . .

The variable $p$ is set to the middle of the known range (i.e., $p = b + (a-b)/2$).

The value $p$ is then tested to see whether it's too low or too high.

If too low, $b$ is set to $p$, and $a$ is left as is.

If too high, $a$ is set to $p$, and $b$ is left as is.

After each pass through the loop, the value of $a - b$ is half its previous value.

When $a-b$ is less than $0.0001$ (an arbitrary tolerance), the loop terminates.

Then the value of $p$ at the end is the desired $r$, which is then adjusted from a monthly rate to an annual rate in the standard way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So basically what it does, is continue calculating `tmp` until `tmp` is below 0.0001. I get all the code and how it works, I just don't understand why it has to be above 0.0001 and why we have to grab the middle of the known range.

Comment: The loop will never get the exact value of $r$, so the choice needs to be made as to when $p$ is "close enough"  to the true $r$. When the $a-b < 0.0001$, the value of $p$ at that stage is no more than $0.0001$ away from the true value of $r$. Thus, the program is using $0.0001$ as an acceptable error tolerance.

Comment: Oh, okay! So if I decrease the $0.0001$ (like to $0.00001$), it will compute more times but get a more precise APR?

Comment: When the bounding interval is $[b,a]$, the next interval will be either $[b,p]$ or $[p,a]$, Choosing $p$ as the midpoint of $[a,b]$ guarantees that the length of the new interval will be half that of the old interval.

Comment: Yes, a smaller tolerance will increase the accuracy at the expense of greater computation time. But be careful -- if the error tolerance is set too low, floating point calculations will produce errors which will dominate the error tolerance, making the apparently more accurate result an illusion.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So the whole `tmp = (loan / repayments) - (1 - Math.pow(1 + p, -months)) / p` line, what exactly does that do? Does it follow some kind of formula? It doesn't look like anything I have seen before.

Comment: Multiply both sides by the (constant) repayment, regard the LHS as effectively zero, and solve for loan. That will give the standard meaning.

Comment: I have no clue what you just said. When do we multiply both sides? What's LHS?

Comment: LHS means "left hand side" (of the equation). In this case, the equation is tmp $= \;...$. If you multiply both sides by repayment, the new LHS is repayment $\times$ tmp. Since tmp is close to zero, and repayment is a fixed constant, the new LHS is also close to zero. If you _replace_ the new LHS by zero, and then solve for loan, you get the usual formula connecting the quantities loan, repayment, number of periods, apr.

Comment: Oh okay, it all starts to make more sense now. I wouldn't exactly say I understnad this fully, but I'm starting to understand the overall of it. Thanks a lot :)