# is it possible to solve it for variable r?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function, transcendental-equations

Here is the annuitet payment formula:
$$p = s \cdot \left(r + \frac{r}{(r+1)^t-1}\right)$$

Is it possible to solve it for rate ?

Comment: i don't think there is an analytic solution, especially for non-integer $t$, but you can certainly use a root-finder to solve numerically

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536653/approximating-the-compond-interest-for-a-loan/1545603#1545603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{p}{s}
    = \frac{r(r+1)^t}{(r+1)^t-1}
    = \frac{r}{1-(r+1)^{-t}}
\end{split}
$$
so for general real $t$, no analytic solution would exist, this is a transcendental equation (kind of like solving $xe^x = c$).

But the RHS is a nice function for $r > 0$, you can certainly solve the equation numerically using a root-finder, like Newton's or Bisection methods.